# Base Types Limitations in Multi-Precision Libraries

Tags: c#

Good afternoon,

Supposing that available memory isn't a constraint, what is the point of having a multi-precision integer library if by storing it's "digits" in an `ulong[]` array you are limited to about, say, (2^64)^(ulong.MaxValue)? I know this is already a pretty big value, but isn't a multi-precision library supposed to be able to represent numbers greater than that one?

**Edit**: this question isn't even specific to .NET because of the 2Gb limit. I am talking about languages in general.

Thank you very much.

Comment: An array with 42 elements is enough for everything.

Answer (score 2):

The point is that there are plenty of applications which *will* need numbers bigger than (say) a 64 or 128 bit integer, but *won't* need numbers bigger than that enormous theoretically one. That's a pretty wide space of numbers.

It's like asking why we have `long` when that's got a limit - and the answer is because there are situations where `int` has too small a range, but the range of `long` is okay.

Have you considered just how big that "pretty big" number really is? Consider the estimate of "number of atoms in the universe" as 10<sup>80</sup>. That won't fit in a `long`, but it would fit in a "relatively small" arbitrary precision integer. If you need to take into account numbers which are larger than 2<sup>17,179,869,176</sup> you should probably think about a different representation.